# Share an ES6 Module between Modules in Monorepo

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have an in-memory DB ES6 singleton module I use for testing and would like to share the single instance between two folders in my monorepo both of which have their own package.json.

I'm not sure which way to go about this.

`/src/graphql/DB/InMemory/`**InMemoryDB.ts**

```
const inMemoryDb = newDb();
inMemoryDb.public.none(fs.readFileSync('001-initial.sql', 'utf8'));
export default inMemoryDb;
```

I want to share this **InMemoryDB.ts** singleton with another module `/src/slack/`

Both `/src/graphql` and `/src/slack` have a **package.json** and a **tsconfig.json** in them.

The reason I want to do this is so that my graphQL service and my slack tests which call that service, both are sharing the same in-memory DB when running tests.

Also tsconfig (ts-node) bitches if I try moving the DB code out of the graphQL folder and into the root of my src, because it says then it's not part of the same module (the graphQL tsconfig bitches because it's trying to import something outside the graphql folder), so that's another problem with trying to move that file out and sharing it between folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using either yarn workspaces or lerna for sharing code in a monorepo. I personally use yarn: https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/workspaces/. One could alternatively try to configure TypeScript and ts-node, but I've found those routes to lead to too complex build configurations. I've never managed to make native ES6 modules work either in a monorepo setting.

The main thing is that you want some tools to symlink the monorepo modules at the project root node_modules from which ts-node can resolve the modules by their package names.

Comment: FYI, I nowadays would recommend NPM >=8 that has workspace support built in.